# Visual C++ Debugging Error - wuser32.pdb not loaded

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I have made a form (GUI) in Visual C++ & while debugging it step by step, I got the following error, which stopped further debugging of the code.

The screenshot of the error is shown below.

How to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good chance further debugging is in fact *not* stopped - seems you tried to step into a system function (implemented in wuser32.dll), and you can't debug this without matching symbols.   You can post a screenshot of the stack window at this point to help us verify.

First, try to just continue (F5 or Shift+F11 to step out).

If for some reason you must view at least function names at this location - check the 'microsoft symbol server' at the screen you show. and click load. After a brief download pause, you should be able to see at least a disassembly window, and hopefully a meaningful name for the current stack frame.